# How to read a plist dictionary, and save the keys (not the values) in array strings of another plist?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, jailbreak, theos

I´m creating a JB tweak with theos in my device.

I would like to read a plist dict like:

```
ASNPrefs.plist

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">

        <dict>
            <key>ASNcenterEnabled</key>
            <false/>
            <key>ASNcornerEnabled</key>
            <false/>
            <key>ASNnoCenterEnabled</key>
            <false/>
            <key>ASNdepthSizeEnabled</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        </plist>
```

and write only the keys as an array into another plist like:

```
ASNkeys.plist

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">

        <dict>
            <key>ASNkeys</key>
            <array>
                <string>ASNcenterEnabled</string>
                <string>ASNcornerEnabled</string>
                <string>ASNnoCenterEnabled</string>
                <string>ASNdepthSizeEnabled</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </plist>
```

I've created a button with this action, but nothing happens:

```
- DEFINED AT BEGINNING OF .MM:


#define prefs @"/User/Library/Preferences/ASNPrefs.plist"
#define asnKeysPath @"/User/Documents/asnKeys.plist"
#define asnKeysDict [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:asnKeysPath] objectForKey:@"keys"]



- IN THE IMPLEMENTATION:


   -(void)ASNkeys {
        NSDictionary *asnPrefs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:prefs];
        NSArray *allKeys = [prefs allKeys];

    [allKeys writeToFile:asnKeysDict atomically:YES];
        }
```

Thank you!

Comment: I don´t know how to deal with this... Suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Ok! sorry... one moment..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally!!

After lot of changes... Thank u so mach CRD!!

```
NSString  *arrayPath;
NSString  *dictPath;
NSString  *origPath;

// Get path to documents directory
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

            if ([paths count] > 0)  {

                origPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"com.maat.asnPrefs.plist"];

                NSDictionary *dictOrig = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:origPath];

                NSArray *ASNKeys = [dictOrig allKeys]; //ForObject:@"true"];

                NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"ASNKeys" : allKeys};

                // Path to save array data
                arrayPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"array.out"];

                // Path to save dictionary
                dictPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"asnKeys.plist"];

                // Write array
                [asnKeys writeToFile:arrayPath atomically:YES];

                // Write dictionary
                [dictionary writeToFile:dictPath atomically:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As your plist is a *dictionary* use `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:` from `NSDictionary` (rather than `arrayWithContentsOfFile:` from `NSArray`). Once you have the dictionary you can use the `allKeys` method to obtain an array of the keys, and then you can write that array to a plist.

HTH

Comment: I will try it later... Now I'm going to leave my kids in school... Thank u for your answer!

Comment: I tryied yesterday so many times... and I can´t figure out how to solve it. I edit the post with new code...

Comment: I did not notice that before your edit you were trying to write into your app bundle, that is not allowed. After your edit you are passing a file path to `pathForResource`, that is incorrect. You should read Apple's [File System Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) for where iOS apps can store files. Are you using the debugger, stepping through your code, and examine the value of every variable? HTH

Comment: Ok! I will try again right now... If it´s not allowed to save inside the app bundle, can I do the save process to a file where it is allowed and then use NSFileManager to copy that saved file back to my app bundle? And another (stupid?) question: is it the same "app bundle" and "tweak bundle"?

Comment: You cannot normally write to the app bundle period, but I see you have the "jailbreak" tag so maybe you can if the app is not signed. Given you are debugging I find introducing your third #define a bit baffling. You need to step through you code and examine the result of every call (or add `NSLog` statements if you can't debug in your environment). The basic `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile`/`allKeys`/`writeToFile` sequence is correct, so your problems lie in the details or elsewhere. Time to sit, read, and debug. HTH

Comment: BTW The third define is there because I need to save inside "keys" key, so the structure is "plist - dict - array - strings".